# Detect Hide Keyboard Event on Android

Tags: android, webview, android-immersive

So I need to keep the immersive mode of an app.
The app has a fullscreen webview on immersive mode but the problem is the webview content has a textbox.
When the user touch on the textbox, it will trigger the softkeyboard which will disable the immersive mode.
I solved the problem when textbox lost its focus, it will trigger a javascriptinterface to reactivated immersive mode again. But the problem is the hide/back button when the softkeyboard is shown.

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okvgR.png)

I tried `onKeyDown`, `dispatchKeyEvent` and `onBackPressed` but none of them was triggering when debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting visibility of soft keyboard, you have to do this :

```
contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {

Rect r = new Rect();
contentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
int screenHeight = contentView.getRootView().getHeight();

int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;
if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
    // keyboard is opened
}
else {
    // keyboard is closed
    }
}
});
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: so i need to bind this on the parent view of the whole layout?